# EVO HTML to PDF Client for UWP Demo issue

Tags: uwp, windows-firewall, evopdf

[image]I'm experiencing problem running EVO HTML to PDF Client for UWP Demo.

I made an installation package of the demo application and deployed it to a separate computer. EvoHtmlToPdfService is installed and working. But when I try to convert HTML to PDF, I get an error (see screenshot). When I run the application on another computer from a Visual Studio environment, everything is fine.

I suspect it's the firewall, which blocks access to 127.0.0.1:40001. But I have no idea how to configure the firewall to allow these calls. Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Has your issue been solved? Does the solution I provided work?

Comment: @AryaDing-MSFT Yes, that was the exact cause. Now everything is ok. Thank you very much again!

Comment: I will turn the comment into an answer, you could mark this answer, which will help others that face same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uwp applications are sandboxed, which can’t access the localhost directly. So could you please try to enable loopback for this uwp app?

Please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback#enabling-loopback-for-a-uwp-application) to know the detailed steps.